# Issues in connecting phpmailer with Office365

Tags: php, email, office365

I need to send email using Office365 mail server from may webpage where user enters their email address.My configurations are as follows:

```
        require("phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug    = 1;
        $mail->Debugoutput  = 'html';
        $mail->Host         = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->Port         = 587;
        $mail->SMTPAuth     = true;
        $mail->Username     = trim($username);//username 
        $mail->Password     = trim($password);//password
        $mail->SMTPSecure   = 'tls';  
        $fromName = 'Test';
        $from     = $myemail;    
        $mail->AddReplyTo($from, $fromName);     
        $mail->From         =   $from;  
        $mail->FromName     =   $fromName;
        $mail->AddAddress($semail);//mail_id which i need to send mail                                               
        $mail->WordWrap     =   80; // set word wrap   
        $mail->MsgHTML($_body);                
        $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
```

When I run the page,it gives following error message

```
Connection: opening
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
Name or service not known (0)
SMTP connect() failed.
**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message 
'SMTP connect() failed.
```

When I use gmail server configuration details(**host:smtp.gmail.com)** ,this is working fine.But my client mail server is with Office365.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ping command in command prompt for the mail server.

```
ping mail.mailservername.com <enter>
```

It gives IP address and another address for the above mail address.I have used the new mail address for the host variable. It works